# Which files are ignored as input by mapper?

Tags: hadoop, filter, mapper

I'm chaining multiple MapReduce jobs and want to pass along/store some meta information (e.g. configuration or name of original input) with the results. At least the file "_SUCCESS" and also anything in the directory "_logs" seams to be ignored.

Are there any filename patterns which are by default ignored by the `InputReader`? Or is this just a fixed limited list?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `FileInputFormat` uses the following [hiddenFileFilter](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.java#72) by default:

```
  private static final PathFilter hiddenFileFilter = new PathFilter(){
      public boolean accept(Path p){
        String name = p.getName(); 
        return !name.startsWith("_") && !name.startsWith("."); 
      }
    };
```

So if you uses any `FileInputFormat` (such as `TextInputFormat`, `KeyValueTextInputFormat`, `SequenceFileInputFormat`), the hidden files (the file name starts with "_" or ".") will be ignored.

You can use [FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.java#FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job%2Cjava.lang.Class%29) to set your custom `PathFilter`. Remember that the `hiddenFileFilter` is always active.

Comment: Do you use the `setInputPathFilter` after or before you configure the job input class?

Comment: Both fine. Just need to set it before running your job.

Comment: Why underscore??

Comment: It's just a convention on HDFS. I don't know the exact reason.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the problem when using links. Those links are dead :(