# Access files that start with underscore in apache spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to access gz files on s3 that start with `_` in Apache Spark. Unfortunately spark deems these files invisible and returns `Input path does not exist: s3n:.../_1013.gz`. If I remove the underscore it finds the file just fine.

I tried adding a custom PathFilter to the hadoopConfig:

```
package CustomReader

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{Path, PathFilter}

class GFilterZip extends PathFilter {
  override def accept(path: Path): Boolean = {
    true
  }
}
// in spark settings
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setClass("mapreduce.input.pathFilter.class", classOf[CustomReader.GFilterZip], classOf[org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathFilter])
```

but I still have the same problem. Any ideas?

System: Apache Spark 1.6.0 with Hadoop 2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files started with _ and . are hidden files.

And the hiddenFileFilter will be always applied. It is added inside method `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus`

check this answer, [which files ignored as input by mapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830264/which-files-ignored-as-input-by-mapper)

Comment: This response, and the one linked, hint at the underlying cause, but do not answer the question: "how to access these files in spark"