# ERROR: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for CSV

Tags: scala, csv, dataframe, apache-spark

I try this basic command to read a CSV in scala:

```
val df = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("sep","|")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv("path/to/_34File.csv")
```

And I get:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for CSV. It must be specified manually.
```

What could be the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access files that start with underscore in apache spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316921/access-files-that-start-with-underscore-in-apache-spark). This should give some insight to why you get an error and a potential solution (except renaming the file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to rename de file from "_34File.csv" to "34File.csv". It's a peculiar case and that worked for me.