# How to access bucketname with underscore in S3 using spark dataframe writer

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am trying to write to bucketname with underscore in S3 and getting the below exception.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The bucketName parameter must be specified.`

The error is not seen if I use some other bucket without underscore.

```
 import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat

 class AcceptAllFileFilter extends PathFilter {
   override def accept(path : Path): Boolean = true
 }


 val hadoopConf = sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
 hadoopConf.setClass(FileInputFormat.PATHFILTER_CLASS, classOf[AcceptAllFileFilter], classOf[PathFilter])

  df.write
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("compression", "gzip")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(s"s3a://$bucketID/$reportID/")
```

Still I am getting the same error. How to access bucketname containing underscore using Spark DF ?

Questions in SO
[Access files that start with underscore in apache spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316921/access-files-that-start-with-underscore-in-apache-spark)

[Which files are ignored as input by mapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830264/which-files-are-ignored-as-input-by-mapper)

Comment: Give a try with this ```.save(s"s3a://${bucketID}/${reportID}/")```

Comment: @SarathChandraVema this will not work. Adding braces will ensure that string is evaluated if a function is passed.

Comment: Bucket name cannot contain underscore according to documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-s3-bucket-naming-requirements.html

Comment: @pasha701 yes this was already created and I need to write to the old bucket :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s3a can only handle valid filenames; the URI parsing fails. AWS doesn't let you create buckets with an _ in any more to stop problems here.

you'll need to write to a modern bucket and then (somehow) copy it via some AWS tools.