# How Spark read file with underline the beginning of the file name?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I use Spark to parse log files, I notice that if the first character of filename is `_` , the result will be empty. Here is my test code:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("TestLog")
  .master("local")
  .getOrCreate();
JavaRDD<String> input = spark.read().text("D:\\_event_2.log").javaRDD();
System.out.println("size : " + input.count());
```

If I modify the file name to `event_2.log`, the code will run it correctly.
I found that the `text` function is defined as:

```
@scala.annotation.varargs
def text(paths: String*): Dataset[String] = {
  format("text").load(paths : _*).as[String](sparkSession.implicits.newStringEncoder)
}
```

I think it could be due to `_` being scala's `placeholder`. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19832011/2214674

Comment: @kinkajou thanks ,  duplicate problem,and i find the reson.

Answer (score 11):

This has nothing to do with Scala. Spark uses Hadoop Input API to read file, which ignore every file that starts with underscore(`_`) or dot (`.`)

I don't know how to disable this in Spark though.

Comment: Thanks , I find the code where ignore file with `_`

Comment: It's overwritable using HadoopRDD with a custom PathFilter

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't see how it's overwritable, because hiddenFileFilter is always active in FileInputFormat

Comment: You would use a different InputFormat

Comment: @cricket_007 that would make a good answer! (It may already be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19832011/1240268).)