# Creating Hive table using HUE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I installed a single node Cloudera to start learning about this technologies. Now, I'm trying to create a table on HUE from a CSV file.

When I try to do it, the table is being created but without any data, just the columns structure and I'm getting the following error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:17
>   Invalid path ''/user/josholsan/ic_data/_glucosa.csv'': No files
>   matching path
>   hdfs://server_name:8020/user/josholsan/ic_data/_glucosa.csv

The error says that there's no files matching this path, but when I try the following in the terminal, the file is right there:

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs//server_name.8020/user/josholsan/ic_data/_glucosa.csv
```

The code HUE is executing to create the table is the following one:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`cpk`
(
  `id` bigint ,
  `numsipcod` string ,
  `valor` bigint ,
  `fecharegistro` string )  ROW FORMAT   SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
  WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = "\t",
  "quoteChar"     = "\"",
  "escapeChar"    = "\\"
  )
  STORED AS TextFile TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count" = "1")
;

LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/josholsan/ic_data/_glucosa.csv' INTO TABLE `test`.`glucosa`;
```

I also tried loading the file from local using LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH.

I don't actually know how to proceed. I've been checking the internet, but what I've found didnt helped me.
There's something that call on my attention and is the permissions for this file when I write the command above this lines, and permissions are: 
**- rw-r--r--**

Anyways, I disabled the permission checking in the HDFS settings.

Anyone with HDFS/HUE/Cloudera knowledge knows which could be the problem in here?
Thanks you so much in advance =)

Comment: Hive expects a **directory** as `LOCATION`, not a file. Also files with leading dots or underscores are usually semaphores or temp files that are _ignored_ by design...

Comment: Thanks you so much @SamsonScharfrichter. Renaming the file witouh leading _ solved the problem. Regarding the directory as LOCATION, how then do you specify the file you want to load into the table? It worked for me just without the _. Thanks you so much again. Can you post it as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TL;DR`    Rename your file -- in the Hadoop ecosystem, data files whose name start with a dot or an underscore are *usually* ignored, by design.

From [which files ignored as input by mapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830264/which-files-ignored-as-input-by-mapper)

> *(... Hadoop source code excerpt...)*
>
> So if you use ... `TextInputFormat` ... the hidden files (the file
>   name starts with **"_"** or **"."**) will be ignored.

The Hive `TextFile` format relies on MapReduce `TextInputFormat` -- hence all files with a leading dot or a leading underscore are ignored; they are supposed to be semaphores (e.g. `_SUCCESS` used by Pig or Spark) or temp directories (e.g. `.impala_insert_staging/`) and the like.

Also, an excerpt from [the Impala documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-11-x/topics/impala_insert.html):

> The INSERT statement has always left behind a hidden work directory
>   inside the data directory of the table. Formerly, this hidden work
>   directory was named `.impala_insert_staging` . In Impala 2.0.1 and
>   later, this directory name is changed to `_impala_insert_staging` .
>   (While HDFS tools are expected to treat names beginning either with
>   underscore and dot as hidden, in practice names beginning with an
>   underscore are more widely supported.)